# SPP Android BT Connection quits after seconds (EEG readings)

Tags: android, bluetooth, real-time

I have created an app that receives data from a bt transmitter (Bluegiga). The readings are from EEG signals. The data rate is 1Khz (I have to admit it's high). Anyway, I acquire some data for some seconds and then the Bluetooth acts like there is no incoming data (which is not true). If I try to disconnect the Bluetooth using the app is clear that there is no more communication with the bt module at the EEG board since it doesn't respond to the desconnection (It has a led that indicates when is connected, and it doesn't turn of/on or anything).

If I decrease the data rate to (let's say 500hz) the app works ok, with some occasional 'quits', but tolerable. If I decrease it more the app works with no problems.

Of curse, by design, my app must work at 1Khz data rate so here is where the problem comes.

I have check some other post, trying to hit some kind of sns but nothing match my problem exactly (anyway I have tried to use the information on them but with no success obviously).

Sometimes I get this message, "dm_pm_timer expires", sometimes no (after the bt stops working).

Sadly there is no indication, Exception or message that can tell me what's going on.

Here is my Code for the BT reception Thread

```
    class BluetoothReadThread extends Thread {


    private final InputStream iStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutputStream;

    private boolean continueReading = true;

    public BluetoothReadThread() {
        InputStream tmp = null;
        OutputStream tmp2 = null;

        try {
            tmp = btSocket.getInputStream();
            tmp2 = btSocket.getOutputStream();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        iStream = tmp;
        mmOutputStream = tmp2;


    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int c;
        int waitCount = 0;
        while (continueReading) {
            try {


                if (iStream.available() > 0) {
                    waitCount = 0;
                    c = iStream.read();
                    readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = c;


                    if (readBufferPosition == bitsExpected) {


                        if (bitsExpected == 22) {
                            ch1 = MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[4], readBuffer[3]);
                            ch2 = MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[6], readBuffer[5]);
                            ch3 = MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[8], readBuffer[7]);
                            ch4 = MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[10], readBuffer[9]);
                            ch5 = MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[12], readBuffer[11]);
                            ch6 = MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[14], readBuffer[13]);
                            ch7 = MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[16], readBuffer[15]);
                            ch8 = MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[18], readBuffer[17]);


                        } else {




                            ch1 = (int) filter_3((double)MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[5], readBuffer[4], readBuffer[3]));
                            ch2 = (int) filter_4((double)MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[8], readBuffer[7], readBuffer[6]));
                            ch3 = (int) filter_2((double)MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[11], readBuffer[10], readBuffer[9]));
                            ch4 = (int) filter_2((double)MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[14], readBuffer[13], readBuffer[12]));
                            ch5 = (int) filter_2((double)MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[17], readBuffer[16], readBuffer[15]));
                            ch6 = (int) filter_2((double)MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[20], readBuffer[19], readBuffer[18]));
                            ch7 = (int) filter_2((double)MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[23], readBuffer[22], readBuffer[21]));
                            ch8 = (int) filter_2((double)MultiplicationCombine(readBuffer[26], readBuffer[25], readBuffer[24]));


                        }

                        Header_int = readBuffer[0];
                        PK_ID_int = readBuffer[1];
                        PK_Counter_int = readBuffer[2];


                        if (downsample++ == downsample_value) {
                            addEntry(ch1 / scaCh1, ch2 / scaCh2, ch3 / scaCh3, ch4 / scaCh4, ch5 / scaCh5, ch6 / scaCh6, ch7 / scaCh7, ch8 / scaCh8);
                            downsample = 0;
                        }
                        //ProgrNum,PacketType,Ch1,Ch2,Ch3,Ch4,Ch5,Ch6,Ch7,Ch8,MRK

                        if (write_open) {
                            osw.write(PK_Counter_int + "," + PK_ID_int + "," + ch1 + "," + ch2 + "," + ch3 + "," + ch4 + "," + ch5 + "," + ch6 + "," + ch7 + "," + ch8 + "," + bolOpenClose + "\n");
                            //osw.write(PK_Counter_int + "," + PK_ID_int + "," + ch1 + "," + ch2 + "," + ch3 + "," + ch4 + "," + ch5 + "," + ch6 + "," + ch7 + "," + ch8 + ","  + "\n");
                        }

                        System.out.println(PK_Counter_int + "," + PK_ID_int + "," + ch1 + "," + ch2 + "," + ch3 + "," + ch4 + "," + ch5 + "," + ch6 + "," + ch7 + "," + ch8 + ", AV=" + iStream.available() );


                        mmOutputStream.write(valueSTR.getBytes());

                        // if(downsample++==14) { safe_copy(readBuffer);  plot=true; downsample=0;}


                        readBufferPosition = 0;
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }


                } 

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e + "\nError sending data + :" + e);
                // Bluetooth error! Stop reading.
                //this.stopAndSendIntent();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
            public void stopAndSendIntent() {

                this.cancel();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(BLUETOOTH_ACTION_DONE_READING);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
    */
    public void cancel() {
        System.out.println("-----Cancelling readThread!!");
        try {
            iStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }
        ;

        continueReading = false;
    }

}
```

It works like this:
I read a received character (c=iStream.read()).
Then I copy this character to an int array until I reach the length of the packet (it can be 22 or 28 (bitsExpected)).

The following part is just filtering and plotting of the signal.

I have tried many other implementations but I get the same result.

Even if I eliminate the part of the filtering and plotting (just reading data) the problem persists.

If instead of working with array, I work with string, i.e, using append() (which should be the same?) I manage to get an working connection (no quits) but, as soon as I manipulate the program using the array everything is the same.

I'm stuck with this for 1 month already, so I will really appreciate any comments, past experience or suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just added this piece of code

```
 if (PK_Counter_int % 100 == 0) mmOutputStream.write(startTring.getBytes());
```

and it works just fine so far.